# How to set carriage return location or equivalent?

Tags: linux, carriage-return

I am looking for a way to set where the carriage return, returns to or an equivalent way to do so.

For example I have a line like this:

`^` denotes cursor location

```
myshell>cat file.txt
                    ^
```

After carriage return it should look like this.

```
myshell>cat file.txt
        ^
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)?

Comment: Are you searching for the `Ctrl-a` key, bound to `beginning-of-line` by default?

Comment: @choroba Yes something of the sorts. I just do not want to move beyond the 'myshell>'

Comment: I don't understand. Is `myshell>` a prompt? Are you in a terminal?

Comment: Is there someway to use `tcsetattr` (termios.h library) call to do this.

Comment: I am making my own shell and the `myshell>` is my prompt

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but are the `Home` and `End` keys not what you're looking for?

Comment: So since I am making my own shell and have changed some tty-attributes (see termios.h) all shortcuts on the keyboard no longer work. I basically have to rewrite what the terminal should do when a button or combination is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably after what's collectively called ANSI escape sequences.  Its hard to search for if you really have no idea what you're after.

This tiny example saves/restores cursor position:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  char cmd_buf[100];
  cmd_buf[0]=0;
  while(strncmp(cmd_buf, "quit", 4))
  {
    printf("mypromt>\033[s <-Cursor should go there\033[u");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(cmd_buf, sizeof(cmd_buf), stdin);
    printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", cmd_buf);
  }
}
```

Note that in `terminator`, `gnome-terminal` and `xterm` on Ubuntu, this "magically" supports `CTRL+U` as-is, but not `CTRL+A` or `CTRL+E`.

There are many, many more sequences available.  The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) is probably the simplest reference to get you started.

**Update**:  Also, unless you're doing this as a learning exercise (which I get the impression Benjamin *is*), to build an interactive shell, you should probably use one of the two well established libraries for shell-style line editing, namely:

- [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (GPLv3, but far more popular)
- [editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) (BSD licensed, closest "second place")

They are the libraries that provide the emacs-style (typical default) and vi-style keybindings and history features we all know and love from `bash`, `python`, `lua`, `perl`, `node`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For positioning on the screen, termios is of limited use (the ioctl's dealing with screensize are not in POSIX), and unless you want to assume a lot about the terminal characteristics, control characters and escape sequences have their limitations.

You can do what's asked in curses using the `filter` function to tell the library you want to use just the current line of the display.  As written, the question is puzzling since it does not mention any output other than the current line.  But for example (this is exactly what was asked):

```
#include <curses.h>

int
main(void)
{   
    int ch, y, x;
    filter();
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    addstr("myshell>");
    getyx(stdscr, y, x);
    while ((ch = getch()) != ERR) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            move(y, x);
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

However, a usable program would do more than that.  There's an example of the [`filter()`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html) function in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html), which you may find useful for reading.  A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: curses / ncurses is a library aimed at building TUIs.  Think `top`, `vi`, or `alsamixer`.  He's building a shell so he wants line editing.  If you're going to use a library for this job, the one you want is [editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) (BSD licensed) or [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (GPL).  These are what you'll find "under the hood" in [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) as well as most scripting languages with an interactive console mode (e.g. Python and Lua).  You could get there with curses (maybe), but its not ideal.